# GCloud AppEngine Task execution returns 403

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-go

using push queues and flexible environment on Google AppEngine I get 403 (Forbidden) error when a task (to be executed on `backend` service), created with `default` service, is executed. The task is successfully pushed to queue, confirmed locally, but the execution of the task(s) fails with log:

```
INFO     2020-12-24 13:42:39,897 module.py:865] default: "POST /tasks/test-handler HTTP/1.1" 403 31
WARNING  2020-12-24 13:42:39,897 taskqueue_stub.py:2158] Task task2 failed to execute. The task has no remaining retries. Failing permanently after 1 retries and 0 seconds
```

The same happens both locally and on production. However, if a task is created with a cron job then the execution works just fine. I am using `dev_appserver.py` with Go 1.11 with the following `.yaml` definitions:

```
# backend service
service: backend
runtime: go111
instance_class: F2

inbound_services:
- warmup
- default

handlers:
- url: /tasks/.*
  login: admin
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

# default app service
service: default
runtime: go111
instance_class: F2

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

Initial API request comes to an `/api` endpoint which then succesfully pushes a queue message using:

```
t := taskqueue.NewPOSTTask(taskURL, url.Values{
    "testParam": {strconv.Itoa(testParam)},
})

if _, err := taskqueue.Add(ctx, t, "test-queue"); err != nil {
    return ErrPublishingTaskToQueue
}
```

My `queue.yaml` definition (in reality I have many more):

```
total_storage_limit: 120M
queue:
- name: test-queue
  rate: 1/s
  bucket_size: 100
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  retry_parameters:
      task_retry_limit: 1
```

Any ideas why I'd be getting 403 (Forbidden) statuses on task execution if a task is not created via a cron job? The documentation and existing resources on this matter do not help much :/

Comment: What do you reffer by "The same happens both locally and on production." are you getting the 403 if you execute this in you local computer, when not deployed to app engine?

Comment: Exactly, using `dev_appserver.py` the task gets pushed to queue and on execution I get 403 response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to make it work. If anyone struggles with getting 403 responses on task execution for push queues on Google AppEngine make sure that you set the right target service. In my example above I was missing `target: backend` in `queue.yaml`:

```
total_storage_limit: 120M
queue:
- name: test-queue
  rate: 1/s
  bucket_size: 100
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  target: backend
  retry_parameters:
      task_retry_limit: 1
```

The problem was that the tasks were created with `default` service which by default means they hit the `default` service, but should hit `backend` service. Unfortunately `default` service had the required endpoint deployed as well, so I got 403 instead of 404.

More details on the `target` field:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref#target